# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Smith' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, mysql, syntax

hope you can help me. I get the error

> "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'Smith' in 'where clause'".

I have a database called "aspirante" and it has a table (I already filled it) named "datos". Here I show you how I created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `datos` (
  `id_asp` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ficha` mediumint(4) NOT NULL,
  `apellido1` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `apellido2` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `genero` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `telefono1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `telefono2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `carrera` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `promedio_sec` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_asp`)
)
```

The method looks like this.

```
void BuscarAspiranteEditar(String id) {
    String sSQL = "";
    String ap1 = "", ap2 = "", nom = "", gen = "", tel1 = "", tel2 = "", car = "", prom = "";

    ConexionMySQL mysql = new ConexionMySQL();
    Connection cn = mysql.Conectar();

    sSQL = "SELECT id_asp, ficha, apellido1, apellido2, nombre, genero, telefono1, telefono2, promedio_sec FROM datos " +
            "WHERE id_asp = "+id;

    try {
        Statement st = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL);

        while (rs.next()) {
            ap1 = rs.getString("apellido1");
            ap2 = rs.getString("apellido2");
            nom = rs.getString("nombre");
            gen = rs.getString("genero");
            tel1 = rs.getString("telefono1");
            tel2 = rs.getString("telefono2");
            car = rs.getString("carrera");
            prom = rs.getString("promedio_sec");
            id_actualizar = id;
        }

        txtPrimerApellido.setText(ap1);
        txtSegundoApellido.setText(ap2);
        txtNombre.setText(nom);
        txtPrimerTelefono.setText(tel1);
        txtSegundoTelefono.setText(tel2);
        txtCarrera.setText(car);
        txtPromedio.setText(prom);

    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

I am not into Java so I hope you can hel me guys, I'd appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the value of `ID`?

Comment: It seems that you're passing a String value to the ID field which is supposed to be an integer value.

Comment: Look up SQL injection. It's very, very bad practice to directly use user's input in an SQL query.

Answer (score 3):

where is your method that passes the parameter `id` ? if your `id` is a string you must enclosed it with quotes `'id'` in like `Where id_asp='"+ id +"'"`

Comment: +1 I think you're right: I think the user entered "smith" instead of a number. It's the only explanation I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like your problem is the id you are passing for the where clause is incorrect.  You are passing in a last name "Smith" instead of the asp id.

As a note about programming with SQL, to be safe you really should be writing your queries with the mysql "?".  This allows mysql to put in the appropriate quotes if needed, and do checks for sql injection.

```
sSQL = "SELECT id_asp, ficha, apellido1, apellido2, nombre, genero, telefono1, telefono2, promedio_sec FROM datos WHERE id_asp = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sSQL);
ps.setObject(1, my_id);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

It's a bit safer and you can pass in variables directly without knowing what needs to be wrapped in quotes etc.